# WSO2 Send a message to another endpoint after finish one transaction

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a situation here where as I need to create a API flow such as below.

[image]

I manage to create an API using the `GET` method and `Call Mediator` for the login request. However, when i change the API method to `POST` (because I need to send something in the body) and using `Call Mediator` for the Login request, it prompt me an error.

I am not sure whether POST method API is not allowed to be using together with the Call Mediator or not.

Is the flow I want to create above, is achievable just using API or do i need to create a Business Process Management Project?

If I wanna use `POST` method together with `Send Mediator`, how would it be ? I was aware that I can not put any mediator after the `Send Mediator`

Any advice would be grateful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error that you got? and Try removing `REST_URL_POSTFIX` property before calling to your endpoint.

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
```